# Is it possible to apply Mavericks side-only dock style to the bottom dock?

Tags: dock, macos

I'm a fan of the Mavericks dock style that's applied when the dock is positioned on the side of the screen. I'm also a fan of having my dock on the bottom of the screen. Can I have both?

Answer (score 1):

They removed this feature from 10.9 for some reason. Just something everyone's gonna have to get used to until a third-party "fix" comes out, or Apple gives in and puts the setting back. There is no way to do this from the dock settings or the Terminal, as was possible with 10.8 and prior.

Comment: Yeah, `defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -bool true` stopped working in 10.9. I didn't find any new preference keys with [gdb](http://osxnotes.com/defaults.html) either.